# Express not serving static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm having an issue serving static javascript files using express. I've tried many different variations of the express documentation to no avail.I've also tried many of the responses to similar questions on S/O.

My folder structure is

```
-MyApp
 -client
 -server
   -public
    foo.js
  server.js
```

server.js:

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');
var path = require('path');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use JWT auth to secure the api, the token can be passed in the authorization header or querystring
app.use(expressJwt({
    secret: config.secret,
    getToken: function (req) {
        if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
            return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
            return req.query.token;
        }
        return null;
    }
}).unless({ path: ['/users/authenticate', '/users/register'] }));
// serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
// routes
app.use('/users', require('./controllers/users.controller'));
app.use('/listings', require('./controllers/listings.controller'));

// start server
var port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 80 : 4000;
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

I am trying to access foo.js through localhost:4000/foo.js but im getting 404 errors constantly.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public')));`

Comment: Does it work when you comment out the JWT middleware above your `serve.static` middleware?

Answer (score 0):

See comment from @MysterX on original post.  Your directory in incorrect.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Should be

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'server/public')));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the help, this sorted it out. How do i then use these script files in the front end? would i just use src="localhost:3000/foo.js" or "/foo.js"?

Comment: Use a relative path: `src="/foo.js"`.  Would you mind accepting the answer so this can help others looking for a similar solution?